# Group query results by similar column name

Tags: database, postgresql

`PostgreSQL version 8.0.4`

I managed to query the database to get this table, lets call it `A`:

[image]

Essentially, this tells me the top 3 levels where a certain achievement was earned the most times. I partitioned it by `row_number()` over `achievement_id` as seen in the picture.

I am stumped on how to query this so that I get a table similar to this:

[image]

With the difference being that `first_max` corresponds to `row_number = 1`, `second_max` to `row_number = 2`, and `third_max` to `row_number = 3`.

The query I use to get the second table:

```
SELECT
  achievement_id,
  level_id AS first_max,
  level_id AS second_max,
  level_id AS third_max
FROM A
WHERE row_number = 1 --Obviously this line is wrong but not sure how to approach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
select 
achievement_id,
max(first_max),
max(second_max),
max(third_max)
from (
SELECT
  achievement_id,
  case when row_number = 1 then level_id end AS first_max,
  case when row_number = 2 then level_id end AS second_max,
  case when row_number = 3 then level_id end AS third_max
FROM A
) B
group by achievement_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [aggregate expressions with FILTER:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#syntax-aggregates)

```
SELECT
    achievement_id,
    sum(level_id) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 1) AS first_max,
    sum(level_id) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 2) AS second_max,
    sum(level_id) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 3) AS third_max
FROM A
GROUP BY 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a71cb/1)

Comment: Surprisingly, I am getting an error `Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "("`. Trying to figure this out. Copied pasted as is, and the problem is in the `sum(level_id) FILTER (WHERE ...` because the query works if I remove those three lines.

Comment: This functionality was introduced in Postgres 9.4. Always *show your PostgreSQL version from SELECT version ()* - from [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info)

Comment: Thank you, I should of specified. Your solution is more elegant than @Vao's but I am running PostgreSQL 8.0.2 so I will accept Vao's solution as the answer and up vote yours. Thanks for the tip.